# How to use different authenticators for API and admin of the site

Tags: api, symfony, authentication

I made a project that is divided into two parts, the front-end part using Vue.js and the back-end part using Symfony and API platform. I did an authentication system on my API platform with JWT tokens like this: https://api-platform.com/docs/core/jwt/ which works like a charm when using it with Vue.js and Axios library.

However, I would like to use the Symfony auth component to create an admin access on my project Symfony, just to allow the admin to create new things and save them in my db. The route will be /admin/whatever. In my security.yaml, I already have a firewall for the API/JWT authentication which looks like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xYCG7.png)

How can I use another which handles the "classic" authentication of Symfony so I can have 2 authentication systems independent on each other?

Edit : I tried this :

```
firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        login:
            lazy: true
            provider: app_user_provider
            json_login:
                check_path: /authentication_token
                username_path: email
                password_path: password
                success_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_success
                failure_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_failure
            jwt: ~
        main:
            lazy: true
            provider: app_user_provider
            custom_authenticator: App\Security\LoginAuthenticator
            logout:
                path: app_logout
```

With this access control :

```
access_control:
         - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
         - { path: ^/profil, roles: ROLE_USER }
         - { path: ^/authentication_token, roles: PUBLIC_ACCESS }
         - { path: ^/api/, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
```

But my /profil route displays this [capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y345Y.png)
My authentication to the api with token while doing a request still works though

Comment: you add  form_login authenticator in security.yaml (like u did for  json_login) check the documentation : https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to have two different configuration in your `security.yaml`. For example `login` for the api connexion and `main` for your app connection

```
# API connexion
login:
  pattern: ^/api/login$
  stateless: true
  json_login:
    check_path: /api/login
    username_path: email
    success_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_success
    failure_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_failure
  
# App connection
main:
  lazy: true
  provider: app_user_provider
  # other configuration ...
```

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**
I may have found the solution (at least it works) :

```
firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        api:
            pattern: ^/api/
            stateless: true
            provider: app_user_provider
            jwt: ~
        login:
            pattern: ^/authentication_token
            json_login:
                check_path: /authentication_token
                username_path: email
                password_path: password
                success_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_success
                failure_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_failure
        main:
            lazy: true
            provider: app_user_provider
            custom_authenticator: App\Security\LoginAuthenticator
            logout:
                path: app_logout


    access_control:
         - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
         - { path: ^/profil, roles: ROLE_USER }
         - { path: ^/authentication_token, roles: PUBLIC_ACCESS }
         - { path: ^/api/, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
```

But I found it nearly randomly, testing a few different configurations, not really knowing what I was doing. So could someone explain me what does this code do exactly ? And why what I tested just before didn't work ? ("/authentication_token" is a route that I call with a POST request, passing it an email and a password and it shall return a token that I use to authenticate for the requests on my api, made with API Platform bundle)